# Does Kuberenetes use the USER instruction from the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Consider a Dockerfile that uses the [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) instruction for example

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot as builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
USER nobody
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

When Kuberenets runs the docker image does it respect the USER instruction or does it ignore it?

If the user does not exist in the K8s cluster does K8s create the user?

Comment: I'd expect it to respect it.  Is something different happening?  Can you include a Pod spec and any useful log messages to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: There are some  aspects of the Dockerfile that K8s ignores like HEALTHCHECK  so I want to know what the official expected behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. That's an important feature when securing containers (although using `gosu` or a similar tool would provide similar security).

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, when it runs a Docker container, it does not directly respect the USER instruction from the Dockerfile. The USER instruction in Dockerfile sets the username or UID to use when running the image, but Kubernetes can manage the user permissions itself.
It can use the securityContext feature to alter the UID/USER
Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

Check the docs for it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

If you are not using this feature it will just "inherit" the Dockerfile insturctions